# Passing parameter inside $location.path in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm just trying to use `$location.path()` in my controller but also passing a custom variable as a parameter. So it would look something like this I guess:

```
$scope.parameter = 'Foo';

$location.path('/myURL/' + $scope.parameter);
```

But that doesn't work. Anyone know how this is supposed to be done in Angular?

Answer (score 186, accepted):

to add Parameters you should use `$location.search()` method so:

```
$location.path('/myURL/').search({param: 'value'});
```

`$location` methods are *chainable*.

this produce :

```
/myURL/?param=value
```

Comment: check spelling, Upper/Lower case and its bindings

Comment: Is there any way to convert this so the url looks like /myUrl/value instead of /myURL/?param=value ?

Comment: you can use .Path('/myURL/' + value).but then it's not called parameter anymore .

Comment: I had to remove the trailing / to get this to work. This code is the working copy

```$location.path('/myURL').search({param: 'value'});```

Answer (score 39):

The another way to add parameter to url is:

```
 $location.path('/myURL/'+ param1);
```

and you can define route to myPage.html:

```
config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/myURL/:param1', {
            templateUrl: 'path/myPage.html',
            controller: newController
            });
    }]);
```

The parameter can then be accessed in newController as follows:

```
var param1= $routeParams.param1;
```

Comment: Is that answer adding a query parameter or a route attribute?

Answer (score 13):

For example if you need to put in your URL one or more parameters:

```
$location.path('/path').search({foo: 'valueFoo', baz:'valueBaz'})
```

in your url will represent

```
/path?foo=valueFoo&baz=valueBaz
```

To get params in an other controller:

```
var urlParams = $location.search();


urlParams.foo will return valueFoo

urlParams.baz will return valueBaz
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  function pathToSomewhere() {
    $stateParams.name= vm.name; //john
    $stateParams.phone= vm.phone; //1234
    $stateParams.dateOfBirth= getDoB(); //10-10-1990

    $location.path("/somewhere/").search($stateParams);

  };
```

This results in the url

```
http://middle-of-nowhere.com/#/somewhere/?name=john&phone=1234&dateOfBirth=10-10-1990
```

This way you don't have to manually type out the parameters inside brackets

Comment: I'm assuming you have $stateParams injected on your controller for this to work.