# Append Param on locationChangeStart

Tags: angularjs

When a user for example hits the back button of my application i do window.history.back() which triggers there `locationChangeStart` in here I want to append `.search({param:'value'})` as per this topic here: [Passing parameter inside $location.path in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22688779/passing-parameter-inside-location-path-in-angular)

Is this possible to be done?

Edit:

This is what I tried:

```
            ]).config(appRoute).run(function ($rootScope, $route) {
                $rootScope.passArgs = {};
                ang.rootScope = $rootScope;
                ang.route = $route;

                $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (a, b, c) {
                    for (var aArg in $rootScope.passArgs) {
                        $route.current.params[aArg] = $rootScope.passArgs[aArg];
                        delete $rootScope.passArgs[aArg];
                    }
                });
```

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is, if there even is a problem, because it's obvious you haven't even tried something.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz I updated my topic with what I tried.

Comment: What's not working? Errors? Etc.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz the path is not changed to include `?param=value&param2=val2`

Comment: Is location.path(yourpath).search({param: 'value'}); not working for you if you try setting it there?

Comment: Well I need to append it during the locationChangeStart or locationChangeSuccess events, as like when user presses back or loads something with `$location.path('/blah')`

Comment: Then try my answer which I've undeleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this instead which will simplify it by a mile.

```
<button class="back-button" ng-click="back()">Go back</button>

$scope.back = function() {
  $location.path('my-path').search({isBack: true});
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Chrill I tried but it dint work :( I tried even outside of this event with just `$location.path().search({p:'val'})` then did `console.log($location.path())` and the path doesnt include `?p=val` :(

Comment: @yatg Exactly what in your code should be in the .search()?

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to set `?isBack=true`

Comment: @yatg Can you post your updated code using my solution?

Comment: Thanks so much for all this attention @Chrill, https://gist.github.com/yajd/b0ae3ac44bcb69740b6f

Comment: @yatg Where do you get isBack from? There's some flawed logic there, you're saying that "if isBack is true, then set it to false, and then set the location to be empty, with a generated hash of isBack='1'. Also this should invoke an infinite redirect loop in theory, but I don't know if it actually does. Because you're saying that when location has been successfully changed, change it again, and so on.

Comment: @yatg I came up with a more simple solution. Take a look.

Comment: Thanks @Chrill yes it seems the only way to pass it is in the same call of $location.path  :( Thanks very much!