# ui.router - getting route parameters on page load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to get some route parameters from my URL, but I have a situation where I need to do it when the page loads, instead of when redirecting from a view.

I have seen this handy app called `ExpressJS` that looks like it does that, but it is designed to run on `nodejs`, not in a web app I do not believe; So I am curious if there is a way to do this with `ui.router`.

http://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html

So basically, when the page loads... if the url is...

`/member/:id/profile`, I want to get the `id`, but I am wanting to avoid hacky string splits and manipulations of the `window.location`. Is this possible?

Comment: no but you can use location.path().search(), [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22688779/passing-parameter-inside-location-path-in-angular)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your state, where url is `/member/:id/profile` resolve the id variable as

```
resolve:{
      id: ['$stateParams', function($stateParams){
          return $stateParams.id;
      }]
   }
```

Then pass the resolved `id` to your controller like.

**Example**

```
controller: function(id){
      $scope.id = id //*** Exists! ***//
   }
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to exist. I am using `ui.router`, not `ngRoute`.

Comment: But that only works if my controller is declared ad-hoc right there with the state, doesn't it? My controller is in another file completely.

Comment: Hrnm, no, this still doesn't work. It doesn't fire when the page loads either.

Comment: Then you inject $location in your controller and call **$location.search().contactId**

Comment: That doesn't work, either. The parameters are not named in the url.

Comment: There's nothing in the url that would tell it what the id is.

Comment: I think this is closer to what I'm needing, as it seems to work: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.util.type:UrlMatcher

Comment: @Ciel Updated the answer