# Using a service for small task

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i been reading about services or factories in angularjs, but im having some trouble finding the best solution, basically i need to pass some data from one controller to another controller, it is a boolean value, but i dont want to create a service for just a small task.

I believe that wouldnt make much sense for just a small job. is there other way in angularjs for this type of situations? Where i could pass small data between controllers. I been looking around in angularjs documentation, but cant figure out the best solution.

Comment: some code sample? what controllers? directive, view?

Answer (score 0):

```
Use $rootScope.emit()
```

in Controller A

```
$rootScope.emit('toggle',true);
```

in Controller B

```
$rootScope.on('toggle', function(value){
})
```

Comment: I would avoid polluting $rootscope

Comment: We are not polluting rootscope , we are using it as a event emitter ,This is standard approach . or use some Eventemitter library

Comment: $rootscope as eventemitter? that's a first

Answer (score 0):

For tiny items, you could use parameters. The the end user, they'd look like a part of the URL string. This is avaible with and without using ngRoute. Have a look at [this stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22688779/passing-parameter-inside-location-path-in-angular).

For more complex data or data that's unsuitable to displaying to an end user, use a service or factory. Seems like overkill, but it gives you greater flexibility.

A $broadcast/$on pattern just gets messy and harder to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

If it's parent/children controller, you can transfer your value with $scope or $emit/$broadcast.

If controllers are on the same level(siblings) you can make wrapper controller for them to store shared data.

If you think there would be similar requirements for other tasks you can consider service, and making it abstract and reusable(some sort of helper).

In any way, you didn't provide enough of info, and there could be a lot of solutions until we see real example.

Answer (score 0):

If your controllers have a child parent relationship (in any level) then you can try with $broadcast or `$emmit` to throw the data and $on to catch that with a a event. Otherwise inject `$rootScope` to one of them and trigger either `$broadCast` on the monitor of `$rootScope`, or `$emmit` on the monitor of `$scope` and catch thet data using `$on('eventName', function(ev, data){})` correspondingly.