# $location path not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tried redirect using below code in angularjs,

```
 if(token.id){
  console.log('something') // something
  $location.path('/signup?token='+token.id+'&email='+token.email);
 }
```

No error in console but the page is not redirecting? Do I have to configure my route?

Solved:

used apply() method and it worked.

Comment: do you see any errors in console?

Comment: are you sure you included the $location library? Also, it won't work if token.id or token.email are undefined

Comment: @Novalink no, both value are present. $location dependency is injected.

Comment: @JennyMok it would be better if you post your solution as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 0):

to add Parameters you should use $location.search() method so:

```
$location.path('/URL/').search({param: 'value'});
```

$location methods are chainable.

this produce :

```
/URL/?param=value
```

Copy Pasted from [Passing parameter inside $location.path in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22688779/passing-parameter-inside-location-path-in-angular)