# Displaying data on a new screen according to the clicked elements on a screen using ng-click

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to basically print out the data about some properties on a new screen which is redirected to that screen after I click on a property name on the main screen .

This is what I have done till now: I hit my api and stored all the data in an array `propertyDetails`. Then on the front part I used ng-repeat="prop in propertyDetials" to iterate through it and printed out all the names in the JSON API on the main screen.

```html
<div ng-repeat="prop in propertyDetails" class="propertyCard"
     ng-click="getPropDetails(prop)">
    <p class="propSummaryName">{{ prop.name }}</p>
</div>
```

Then in my controller js I did:

```
$scope.getPropDetails = function(prop){
    $location.path('/propertyDetailScreen');
    console.log(prop.name);
    $scope.propName = prop.name;  
}
```

now back to html, on my propertyDetailScreen

```html
<p> {{ propName }} </p>
```

I have done the routing. When I run this what happens is that when I click on a property it goes to the new screen. I can see the logged output in console. But the Name is not displayed on the screen. How do I achieve this?

Comment: See [ngRouter example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#examples).

Comment: Please don't ask the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56808443/show-data-based-on-what-is-clicked-in-a-new-screen-using-angularjs?noredirect=1) when you are unhappy with answers.

Comment: What do you mean when you say you have done the routing? Server side routing will destroy all client-side data. AngularJS data does not persist through full page loads. To preserve data the app needs to do client-side routing.

Answer (score 0):

When you redirect to a new state with:

```
$location.path('/propertyDetailScreen');
```

this state has another $scope, a new one.
What you need to do is to pass the value you want as a parameter to the new state.
There are some ways to achieve that using $location.path. Check these answers: [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22688779/passing-parameter-inside-location-path-in-angular)

Comment: I tried a lot man. I just face a problem some where which I dont understand why is ti happening. I have been busting my brains for over 5 hours now. Please help me?I checked out the link, I literally did everything told there.But somehow, everytime I end up with errors. I got the params, I did everything uut idk

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.getPropDetails = function(prop){
  $location.path('/propertyDetailScreen/'+ prop.name);
}
```

**Next screen**

Create a new route file:

1) **In route file**

```
config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/propertyDetailScreen/:param1', {
            templateUrl: 'path/propertyDetailScreen.html',
            controller: newController
            });
    }]);
```

2) In controller file:

First Inject `$routeParams` as arguments

`$scope.name = $routeParams.param1;`

3) **In HTML**

`{{ name }}`

Let me know you have any question.

Comment: Did exactly what you told me to. Error: Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module yorapp due to:
[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeProvider

Comment: `ngRoute` has been moved to its own module. If you are getting this error, be sure that you've installed `ngRoute`.

Comment: Do you have install route lib? If then add.

Comment: can we talk personally if you dont have a prob?

Comment: yu sure. I am always open for help.